# Formatting data from a txt file

Tags: python, file, text, string-formatting

I have txt file that from which I want to produce a string in a certain way. For example, if the file contained:

```
Num Date____ Bank Type_______ NCu CCu Buy___________ Sell__________
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 840 USD 0001,074800000 0001,050800000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 826 GBP 0000,863900000 0000,839900000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 756 CHF 0001,094200000 0001,060200000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 191 HRK 0007,650800000 0007,420800000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 348 HUF 0315,890000000 0307,090000000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 941 RSD 0124,940000000 0121,140000000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 977 BAM 0001,985000000 0001,919000000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 807 MKD 0062,110000000 0060,290000000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 643 RUB 0071,939300000 0066,539300000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 203 CZK 0027,544000000 0026,544000000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 985 PLN 0004,509000000 0004,361000000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 975 BGN 0001,979000000 0001,925000000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 578 NOK 0009,247100000 0008,907100000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 752 SEK 0009,929000000 0009,609000000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 208 DKK 0007,552100000 0007,328100000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 036 AUD 0001,444400000 0001,400400000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 124 CAD 0001,452800000 0001,404800000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 392 JPY 0121,830000000 0118,030000000
```

The code would produce something along the lines of:

```
GBP......0.8639......0.8399
USD......1.0748......1.0508
RUB.....71.9393.....66.5393
HRK......7.6508......7.4208
HUF....315.8900....307.0900
```

and so on for all of the currencies.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Send some code you have done !

Comment: It is also not clear if you want to receive average numbers for each currency, or just filter each line.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file appears to be using a fixed format, so the following kind of approach should work:

```
fields = [slice(34, 37), slice(38, 52), slice(53, 67)]

with open('input.txt') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    header = next(f_input)

    for row in f_input:
        cols = [row[field] for field in fields]
        cols[1] = '{:.>12.4f}'.format(float(cols[1].replace(',', '.')))
        cols[2] = '{:.>12.4f}'.format(float(cols[2].replace(',', '.')))
        f_output.write(''.join(cols) + '\n')
```

Giving you the following output:

```
USD......1.0748......1.0508
GBP......0.8639......0.8399
CHF......1.0942......1.0602
HRK......7.6508......7.4208
HUF....315.8900....307.0900
RSD....124.9400....121.1400
BAM......1.9850......1.9190
MKD.....62.1100.....60.2900
RUB.....71.9393.....66.5393
CZK.....27.5440.....26.5440
PLN......4.5090......4.3610
BGN......1.9790......1.9250
NOK......9.2471......8.9071
SEK......9.9290......9.6090
DKK......7.5521......7.3281
AUD......1.4444......1.4004
CAD......1.4528......1.4048
JPY....121.8300....118.0300
```

This uses a list of `slice` objects to hold where in each row the fields are. These are extracted using a list comprehension. The 2nd and 3rd columns are then converted to floats and formatted with leading dots and four decimal places. The resulting list is then written out to a file.